# Sort third list using sorting resulting from two list sort?

Tags: python, list, sorting

Say I have three lists:

```
X = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
Y = [ 0,   1,   1,    0,   1,   2,   2,   0,   1]
Z = [ 5,   2,   3,    1,   4,   9,   6,   0,   7]
```

I can sort X according to Y rather easily:

```
XY_sort = [x for _,x in sorted(zip(Y,X))]
print(XY_sort)  # ["a", "d", "h", "b", "c", "e", "i", "f", "g"]
```

Doubts arise when I want to sort list Z according to the sorting that produced XY_sort. Ideally, I want to end up with:

```
Z_sort = [5,   1,   0,   2,   3,   4,   7,   9,   6]
```

I'm guessing the best way to do this would be to somehow store the sorted indices of X when it gets sorted into XY_sort, then using those to sort Z, but I don't know how I would go about doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a key argument to call out the elements of the tuple that `zip` produces to sort as you desire:

```
>>> sorted(zip(X,Y,Z), key=lambda t: (t[1], t[0]))
[('a', 0, 5), ('d', 0, 1), ('h', 0, 0), ... ('f', 2, 9), ('g', 2, 6)]
```

Then filter out `X` and `Y` in the resulting tuple:

```
>>> [z for x,y,z in sorted(zip(X,Y,Z), key=lambda t: (t[1], t[0]))]
[5, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6]
```

The advantage here is that `Z` is not considered in the sort order at all; only the two elements in the key function that match `X` and `Y` are used.

---

BTW: I *usually* answer all Python questions with Python **3** syntax. However, Python **2** had a really great syntax for lambda functions that would automatically unpack a tuple passed as an argument.

**Python 2 only example:**

```
>>> sorted(zip(X,Y,Z), key=lambda (x,y,z): (y, x))
[('a', 0, 5), ('d', 0, 1), ... ('f', 2, 9), ('g', 2, 6)]
>>> [z for x,y,z in sorted(zip(X,Y,Z), key=lambda (x,y,z): (y, x))]
[5, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6]
```

That syntax [has been retired](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) unfortunately....

---

As stated in comments, this works too:

```
>>> [z for z,y,x in sorted(zip(Z,Y,X), key=lambda t: t[1:])]
[5, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6]
```

Comment: You could use `key=lambda t: t[:2]` (if you `zip(Y,X,Z)`).

Comment: @superbrain: That is creative. I added that. I usually prefer to explicitly call out the elements used just so I don't have to think too much.

Comment: Hope you're a little less sad now about that loss of Python 2's syntax :-) (I liked that a lot, too...)

Answer (score 6):

You can sort the same way. It will sort first by Y, then X, if these are both the same it will sort by Z:

```
X = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
Y = [ 0,   1,   1,    0,   1,   2,   2,   0,   1]
Z = [ 5,   2,   3,    1,   4,   9,   6,   0,   7]


XYZ_sort = [z for y,x,z in sorted(zip(Y,X,Z))]
# [5, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6]
```

*[Edit thanks to the commenter's tenacity]*
If it's possible that `X-Y` combinations are not unique, and if it's important that you preserve the relative order of Z in those cases, you can pass [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as the key to the sort for a clean solution:

```
from operator import itemgetter

X = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "a"]
Y = [ 0,   1,   1,   0,  0,   1,   2,   2,   0,   1,  0]
Z = [ 5,   2,   3,  -1,  1,   4,   9,   6,   0,   7,  1]

XYZ_sort = [z for y,x,z in sorted(zip(Y,X,Z), key=itemgetter(0, 1))]

#preseves the relative order of 5, -1, and 1
# [5, -1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6]
```

Answer (score -1):

You say "sort X according to Y", but then you really sort X according to Y **and X**. If you truly sorted it only by Y, you could use the same for Z as well.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Nah I don't think so. I'm telling them how to achieve what they apparently really want.